# El significado de “son más de su época”

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Quisiera saber el significado de “son más de su época” en “Gente que se cree que viene a revolucionar en algo y son más de su época que un iPhone”, que es una opinión publicada por alguien en Twitter. Parece que esa opinión tiene una connotación negativa, pero no estoy seguro. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que en este caso “gente que es de su época” significa “gente con costumbres e ideas propias de su tiempo”, es decir, gente que no es revolucionaria ni adelantada a su época sino personas comunes. Esta “gente de su época” no trae ideas nuevas y por lo tanto no puede cambiar (revolucionar) nada.

Answer (score 0):

Algo así como "chapado a la antigua" (no tan antigua como si fuese un viejo, pero antigua tiene que ser porque se trata necesariamente de una generación pasada), y en el contexto "vienen a descubrir la pólvora".